# Run Vue Js project on local device

Tags: vue.js

I've created my simple Receipt project using Vue js and i want to run it on my local machine without using VS code or writing command .. just like normal file that can be open and used by any user

is there a way to do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `npm run build`?

Comment: that creates a dist folder and the index.html file is not working

Comment: Why is it not working? Do you get any errors?

Comment: The dist directory is an application bundle meant to be served by an HTTP server.  It is not possible to open index.html and have the app run over the `file://` protocol.  Closest thing I can think of to do what you want would be to port your Vue app into an Electron powered desktop app.  There are [tools](https://nklayman.github.io/vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder/) out there that can help with that